# Passing parcelable object to new activity returns null

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent, parcelable

I am passing an object of parcelable data class to an activity for simple string 
I am able to put it in an intent and pass it to another activity but when I  entered a new string list in my object the object (now including an list) is not being passed to other activity.

here is my data class"

```
package com.example.user.shoppy.models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class ProductModel implements Parcelable {

String product_name, description, price, currency, location, userId, image, 
product_Id,featuredImage;

List<String> imagesNames;

public ProductModel() {
}



// this constructor is getting all the string variables
public ProductModel(String product_Id, String product_name, String description, String price, String currency, String userId, String location) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.location = location;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.product_Id = product_Id;
}
// this constructor is getting all the string variables but also an list 
public ProductModel(String product_id, String product_name, String des, String price, String currency, String userId, String location, String featuredImage, List imagesNames) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
    this.description = des;
    this.price = price;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.location = location;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.product_Id = product_id;
    this.featuredImage = featuredImage;
    this.imagesNames = imagesNames;
}


public String getProduct_Id() {
    return product_Id;
}

public void setProduct_Id(String product_Id) {
    this.product_Id = product_Id;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getProduct_name() {
    return product_name;
}

public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(String currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getFeaturedImage() {        return featuredImage;    }

public void setFeaturedImage(String featuredImage) {        this.featuredImage = featuredImage;    }

public List<String> getImagesNames() {        return imagesNames;    }

public void setImagesNames(List<String> imagesNames) {        this.imagesNames = imagesNames;    }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(product_name);
    dest.writeString(price);
    dest.writeString(currency);
    dest.writeString(location);
    dest.writeString(userId);
    dest.writeString(image);
    dest.writeString(product_Id);
    dest.writeString(featuredImage);
    dest.writeStringList(imagesNames);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProductModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ProductModel>() {
    @Override
    public ProductModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ProductModel(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ProductModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ProductModel[size];
    }
};

private ProductModel(@NonNull Parcel in) {
    description = in.readString();
    product_name = in.readString();
    price = in.readString();
    currency = in.readString();
    location = in.readString();
    userId = in.readString();
    image = in.readString();
    product_Id = in.readString();
    featuredImage=in.readString();
    in.readList(imagesNames,String.class.getClassLoader());
}
}
```

and here are remaining code:

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ProductSellingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("currentProductModel", currentProductModel);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

and now my intent receiving classs

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
    currentProductModel= (ProductModel) intent.getParcelableExtra(ProductSellingActivity.INTENTNAME);
```

Comment: Make sure your key `currentProductModel` name is same in receiving activity

Comment: it is same, the problem is with the list data type. its work fine with simple Strings.......

Comment: just wanted to make sure that does data get fill in `currentProductModel` in this object. put a breakpoint on line `mContext.startActivity(intent);` and check values for that object

Comment: yes "currentProductModel"  object have all the values, but when it reaches the next activity the debugger shows that intent have extras but no value is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

While receiving intent in second activity key should be the same.

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
currentProductModel= (ProductModel) intent.getParcelableExtra("currentProductModel");
```

try this.

Comment: I have made a global variable as follows, so key name is same.

` private final static String INTENTNAME="currentProductModel"; `

Answer (score 0):

I think that your ProductModel is not correctly recreated in the new Activity.

Try this in your parcel implementation:

```
imagesNames = in.readArrayList(ProductModel.class.getClassLoader());
```